Can I store push widows notifications from twitter in chrome (web notifications) to a file using python
From My twitter account I get push widows notifications from some accounts where I have turned web notifiactions on in chrome in windows 11. Sometimes they are quite fast and I miss some of them as only last 20 notifications are shown in action centre.
Is there a solution from any of these options

a python program is able to pasrse some log file or listen to these web notifications and store them in text or csv
Without subscibing to any paid service, I can get last few tweets from select  twitter users using some python code.
Any other way to acheive this.

